# Property graph (Neo4j) design: Single node with multiple relations or new nodes for each event occurence?

Tags: graph, neo4j, spring-data-neo4j, spring-data-graph, property-graph

Let us say I've two Leagues L1 and L2. Each league can have multiple rounds like Playoffs, Quarterfinals, Semifinals and Finals. Moreover, I also need to represent the **happens_after** fact like Quarterfinals happens after Playoffs, Semifinals happens after the Quarterfinals and Finals happens after the Semifinals.

**Questions**

Should my graph have one node for each of these rounds and each League should link to these rounds? This way we are just creating new relationships (e.g. both L1 and L2 will have a relationship to Playoffs) but there is only one Playoff node. However, this limits the **happens_after** relationship because some leagues can have more rounds (for e.g. Round 2 can come before Quarterfinals). Is there a better way to represent this?

**Use-cases**

1. Need to be able to find all the rounds of a given league.
2. Need to be able to find the **order** of all the rounds of a given league and the dates each of these happened.

**EDIT**

[image]

Answer (score 2):

In general everything that has an identify on its own should become a node. Relationships tie the "things" together.

Not sure if I fully understand your domain. L1, L2 and each round would be nodes. The relationship league -> round indicates that a given league takes part in the round.

The temporal order within the rounds can be modeled by having BEFORE and/or AFTER relationships among them. This way you build a linked (or a double linked) list of rounds.
Another way to express temporal order would be to store a indexed timestamp property for the round. If you're just interested in before or after and not on absolute time, the first approach (linked list) seems to fit better.

Comment: I've added picture to my post. L1 has 2 levels (Playoffs and Round 2), but L2 has two "different" levels (Playoffs and then Quarterfinals). How do you write a query to determine all the levels for a given league here?

Comment: The question is whether to share the round nodes or create them per league. Sharing makes the query complex but reduces the number of nodes (not a concern actually). Creating then for each league keeps the things simple.

Comment: If the number of leagues is limited, you can encode the league itself in the "next" relationship by using "next_l1" and "next_l2". Also the league should have a next_l1/l2 relationship to the first round (palyoff). A query to get all the rounds in temporal order is then: `start l=node:league(leagues:'L1') match l-[:NEXT_L1*]->n return n`

Comment: +1 NEXT_L1 is a good idea but I can't represent this in spring-data-neo4j as each new league means a new relationship type and relationships are statically typed in spring-data-neo4j